# How can I assign a variable type based on an input?

Tags: c++, c++17

I would like to be able to assign a variable type depending on a keyword that I read in. 
For example: I read the line "a:17". Because I see the "a", I know that the following will be an integer and I can store it as so. 
But if I saw "b:x", then because I see the "b", I know that what follows will be a character, and so I can store it as a character. 
Similarly, if I saw "c:hello", then the "c" tells me that what follows is a string and I can store it as a string.

I have 6 of these types, from signed integers to byte arrays. What I wanted to do was create a structure that stored the type, and then had one variable which depended on the type. Ideally:

```
struct optional {
    char type;
    *variable type* value;
}
```

I realize that I could just store 6 variables, one for each type that I might read. The reason I haven't done so is because I am not sure if that will take up a lot of memory. If I create 1000 instances of this structure, and each one only needs 1 out of those 6 variables, are the other 5 variables taking any memory at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: If `std::variant` is not available because your compiler is not up to date, [consider a `union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union).

Comment: Or boost::variant.